# Can't DROP "MUL" key/index in MySQL - column listed in SHOW

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1091

I'm using mysql-server-5.0.45-7.el5 on CentOs 5.

In my database, there is a table which, I don't know when, a MUL key was created (the database is shared, under control of a group), and now when I try to insert some values I get an error like shown above:

```
Duplicate entry '2-1-2004-09-11 13:13:41.526' for key 2:INSERT INTO ephemeris SET
EPH_TYPE_ID = 1, FILENAME = 'CBERS_2_CCD1_DRD_2004_09_11.13_13_23', ID = 0, 
IS_NEW = 1, SATELLITE_ID = 2, TIME = '2004-09-11 13:13:41.526'
```

I got this error once, and I tried `ALTER TABLE ephemeris DROP INDEX SATELLITE_ID;`
It worked at first time, but now the same constraint appeared and it didn't worked at all.

The structure of table (resumed):

```
mysql> show columns from ephemeris;

+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| SATELLITE_ID | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| EPH_TYPE_ID  | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
```

When I type the `ALTER TABLE` command, mysql returns as:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE ephemeris DROP INDEX ephemeris.SATELLITE_ID ;
ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'SATELLITE_ID'; check that column/key exists
```

Anybody have already gotten this error? Any help?

Rgds.

Comment: What is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ephemeris`?

Comment: I'm going to answer in parts:

`mysql> show create table ephemeris;
| Table     | Create Table | ephemeris | CREATE TABLE 'ephemeris' (
  'ID' int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  'SATELLITE_ID' int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  'EPH_TYPE_ID' int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  'TIME' varchar(26) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  ('ID'),
  UNIQUE KEY 'SATTYPTIM' ('SATELLITE_ID','EPH_TYPE_ID','TIME')
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3504219 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |`

Comment: Click "edit" to update the content of your initial question, it will be easier to read.

Comment: Could you understand? The content was edited, and I can't edit anymore...

Comment: Reading the output from previous command, I can do alter table ephemeris DROP INDEX SATTYPTIM; and it will work. Thanks

Comment: [Click here to edit link your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13256545/edit). This "edit" link is located just below your question.

Answer (score 6):

You need to first drop the foreign key constraint, then drop the index.

```
mysql> show create table a;

| CREATE TABLE `a` (
`id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`sal` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`b_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `b_id` (`b_id`),
CONSTRAINT `a_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`) REFERENCES `b` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 

mysql> alter table a drop foreign key `a_ibfk_1`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table a drop index `b_id`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```